# MySQL - How to check whether all values of a given SELECTed row are equals?

Tags: mysql, select

Using MySQL, how can i SELECT all rows whose values are equals ? For instance, suppose a SELECT of a given table as follows

```
COLUMN_A   COLUMN_B   COLUMN_C ... COLUMN_N
       1          2          4            7
       6          3          5            6
       5          5          5            5
       7          1          3            4
       3          3          3            3
```

I need a SELECT which should return

```
COLUMN_A   COLUMN_B   COLUMN_C ... COLUMN_N
       5          5          5            5
       3          3          3            3
```

Comment: `where (column_a = column_b and column_a = column_c ...)`

Comment: Non-intuitive approach: `where least(column_a, column_b, ...) = greatest(column_a, column_b, ...)`

Comment: Oh, and be wary of `null`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT
   column_a
  ,column_b
  ,column_c
  ,column_d
FROM mytable
WHERE column_a = column_b
AND   column_a = column_c
AND   column_a = column_d
```

ETC.

[SQL Fiddle Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9976e/6/0)

**My Notes**

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
(
column_a int,
column_b int,
column_c int,
column_d int
);

INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (1,2,4,7);
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (6,3,5,6);
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (5,5,5,5);
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (7,1,3,4);
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (3,3,3,3);
```

Comment: Updated answer as my previous one was the wrong approach. It should be one column (column_a) we are comparing to all columns. Not a pair of columns as each pair may be equal to the pair, but not to the entire row.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Equality is transitive so we just need to compare our values against a given reference. Congrats!!!

Answer (score 2):

You could [unpivot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184381/mysql-turn-table-into-different-table) the data.  I'm going to add an surrogate ID column to your table because this will make reconciliation easier.  The unpivoted data will look like this:

```
id  SourceCol SourceVal
1   A         3
1   B         3
1   C         3
...
1   N         3
2   A         5
2   B         5
2   C         5
...
2   N         5
```

Then you group by ID and SourceVal, and only return the sets with all matches

```
select
    ID
from UnPivotedTable
group by ID, SourceVal
having count(*) = N     -- N = however many columns you have in the source table.
```

The result set can be joined back to the original table to get the full rows.  If you don't add the surrogate ID you'll have to join back to the source table on every column:

```
select
    col_A ... Col_N
from Source as s
inner join UnPivotResult as u -- this is the result set from the previous query
on s.col_A = u.SourceVal
and s.col_B = u.SourceVal
...
and s.col_N = u.SourceVal
```

.. which is likely to be ugly.

I'm not entirely *au fait* with MySQL syntax so apologies if I'm off by a few characters.

Comment: Yes, it also works, but MySQL PIVOT syntax is by far most difficult than a single select. Thank you anyway.